# Integrating phpBB + Wordpress + Disqus + WP Social Login

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, disqus, phpbb

Ok, this might be a bit tricky.

I run a WP-site with an attached phpBB forum and would like to integrate at the same time: phpBB + Wordpress + Disqus + WP Social Login.

phpBB + Wordpress linked successfully  thanks to WP phpBB Bridge.

However, I can't make Disqus sign-in through my WP site work.  Plus, I doubt I will manage to integrate WP Social Login too.

Any advice guys?

Otherwise I might drop phpBB and go for Simple-Press plugin instead.  Less performing, but easier.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? How do you know you can't make Disqus work?

Answer (score 0):

For phpBB 3.0.12 and up to version 4.1 WordPress, you can use the WP-United plugin found on the WordPress plugin repository.  It has a handful of features to customize where and how user accounts are created when registration happens. So if the social signup still triggers the same login/registration functions in WP then the phpBB accounts should be made as well, if not when the user logs into either system for the first time. I'm not using the social login plugin though.

I'm currently using this combination and not really on a live site.  It works but I don't know if it will in the future.  Since the last I used this mod there have been a couple updates to both the plugin and to phpBB 3.0.x, so you may need to make a few manual changes pre or post running MODx/AutoMOD but it should still work.

Recently the WP-United website which housed a support forum has changed and the author seems to be no longer offering public support around the plugin.
If you plan to update or already have updated to phpBB 3.1.x then this mod probably wont work at all, due to the new extensions system they have now.  However I have not tried this myself.

There does not appear to be any working options for integrating phpBB 3.1.x and WordPress 3.x/4.x at this time.